# ibatis database name with special characters

Tags: html, tomcat, ibatis

I have to generate an html report regarding a few databases.

I am using ibatis on the server side.
One of the tables has a 'degree' sign as a part of its name.
The issue is, when I print this name in html file, the degree signs converts to ? , which is not what I want.

Is there a way , that I can get the database name with special characters and show it in the same way.

### Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it might be an encoding issue between the database and your code. Make sure, that you use the same setting as the database.

Most databases use UTF-8 as encoding, nowadays. But HTML is, by default, ISO8859 and Tomcat assumes all HTML to be the same.

I guess you cannot simply rename that table and be done with it, right?

Comment: @nfechner:No I cant simply rename :P.

Comment: What about my actual tip. Did you check the encodings?

Comment: I specifically mentioned the coding in html as UTF-8 but I still face the issue.Is there a way to confirm , what kind of encoding is the DB and tomcat using??

Comment: Tomcat depends on your settings in server.xml: Check [URIEncoding](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) on your AJP and HTTP connectors. It defaults to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: For the database it depends on your DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, etc) and the driver you have chosen.

Comment: thanks @nfechnet.i will try to make the changes and let you know.

Comment: @nfechnet : seems like I will not get permissions to change settings on the DB... its third party... any other things I should try??

Comment: You can recode the result you get from the database: `String recodedResult = new String(result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")`. You might have to test a bit to get the correct combination.